# How to pass variables from one method (which is having arguments) to main method?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have written java class to calculate the response time of a given website and store the data in a file. So I want to call the method which is having calculation. And it has arguments too. And when I call that method in main method and it is showing some errors. Can someone fix my bugs? Here is my code.

```
   public class NewClass1 {
        private static int start = 0;
        private static int finish = 0;
        public static int[] time1=new int[20];
        private static  DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        private static  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        public static String[] today = new String[4];


        public static NewClass2 myclass(String website)  throws Exception {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("google.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("current time                response time");


             NewClass2 getData=new NewClass2();

             DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

            for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            {
            String stack_url = website;

            try {
                    URL url = new URL(stack_url);
                     HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpUrlConnect.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    start = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                    httpUrlConnect.connect();

                    if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) 
                    {
                        finish = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                        System.out.println(stack_url + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " took " + (finish-start) + " Milli Seconds.");
                    }

                    if (httpUrlConnect.getResponseCode() == httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) 
                    {
                    System.out.println(stack_url + " - " + httpUrlConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - " + httpUrlConnect.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
                    } 
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                }


                 LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

                 finish = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                 System.out.println(stack_url + " took  "+ (finish-start)+" milliseconds.  at  "+dtf.format(now));
                 String day = dtf.format(now);
                 try{
                 bw.write(day+"             ");
                 bw.write(finish-start);
                 }
                 catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Problem writing to the file statsTest.txt");
                } 

                  today[i]= dtf.format(now);
                  time1[i]=finish-start;

                    Thread.sleep(6000);
             }
            bw.close();
            fw.close();

            getData.settime(time1);
            getData.settoday(today);

            return getData;

   }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     NewClass1 mynewclass =new NewClass1();

     mynewclass.myclass();

 }
   }
```

Comment: ...and what are the errors?

Comment: method naming is not proper. please modify your code, so you can understand it more easily. 1) Since myclass is  a static method with a single argument, you could invoke it without creating an object of NewClass1. 2) Since myclass method expects an argument, pass that argument in your main method.

Comment: Downvote for stupid title which has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I tried to do it I am not getting so can you please do the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `myclass` function takes a `String` parameter. In `main` you call it with no parameters.

Comment: that is the problem I dont know how to take a parameter inside to that function .Can you give me a solution for that

Comment: For example, `mynewclass.myclass("SomeString");"` or `String x = "SomeString"; mynewclass.myclass(x);`

Answer (score 0):

In your myclass method, it takes a String parameter :

**Method myclass**

```
public static NewClass2 myclass(String website)  throws Exception {
    //your code
}
```

Therefore, when you call it you should pass in String argument such as below:

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    NewClass1 mynewclass =new NewClass1();
    String website = "https://www.google.com";

    MyClass2 yourVariableName = mynewclass.myclass(website);

}
```

Since you also return a variable you should hold it like this